# iOS - git doesn't recognize Localizable.strings file to commit

Tags: xcode, git, localizable.strings

I work with:

OS X El Capitan 10.11.5

XCode 8.2.1

Swift 3.0

I have two **Localizable.strings** files (English and Spanish) in my project that work perfect. 
This files are in their respective folders:

- en.lproj
- es.lproj

For some reason **git doesn't recognize these two Localizable.strings** files when I commit changes in my project.

I made a test changing the extension from *.strings to *.txt and it was recognized instantly by git as a change available to be commited.

I tried some "solutions" I found but they don't work at all:

1. Added a file named `.gitattributes` with the following text in it:  `*.strings diff=localizablestrings`
2. In the file `config` in the folder `.git` I added the following code:

`[diff "localizablestrings"]
textconv = "iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8"`

Nothing made git recognize my Localizable.strings. May you please help me find what am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at your .gitignore?

Comment: a strings file is a text file and if you don't ignore it, it works fine. plz post the gitignore a screenshot of the folder, output of git status and a git log path_to/Localizable.strings

Comment: I did not add a .gitignore file and I checked the folder and there's no .gitignore file in my project.

Comment: Please, anyone can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found how to fix this:

First I forced through terminal this way:

> git add -f folderWhereTheFilesAre/Localizable.strings

This forced git to recognize these files.

I was going to commit this but thougth it's better to do it without forcing it so I added a .gitignore file with the following in it:

```
!/FolderName/en.lproj/*
!/FolderName/es.lproj/*
```

Then I commited (and pushed) only this .gitignore file and then both Terminal and SourceTree finally detected these two files without forcing it. Then I could commit and push the `Localizable.strings`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new line `*.strings binary=false` to file `<repo_root>/.git/info/attributes`. (If there is no such file in your repo, create one.)